# DATA Statement issue : Not enough variables

Tags: fortran

I'm facing difficulties to figure out why my code is giving me this error

```
error 281 - Not enough variables in DATA statement
```

I am using the latest Silverfrost on Windows 8. The relevant piece of my module is,

```
...
INTEGER, parameter :: maxExampleTypes     =   5
TYPE ExampleInfo
    CHARACTER (len=50) :: ExDeckName
    INTEGER A(maxExampleTypes)
    INTEGER ExUnits
ENDTYPE ExampleInfo
TYPE(ExampleInfo) :: Example(10)
DATA Example(1)%ExDeckName/'test.dck'/
DATA Example(1)%A/1,2,3,4,5/
...
```

Curiously, when I only specify one variable for `A` with

```
DATA Example(1)%A/1/
```

the error disappears.

Have you got any idea where it could come from?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you (a) want to set default values the first time you use the subroutine, (b) set initial values every time the subroutine is called, or (c) use parameters?

Comment: (a), I try to set default values but last line "DATA Example(1)%A/1,2,3,4,5/" gives me an error

Comment: Not to approve of the usage or anything, but this code works with gfortran, and i see no reason why it should not.  Call it a bug in Silverfrost that isn't worth worrying about..

Comment: out of curiosity try giving a 50 char string..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would never use the `DATA` statement in modern Fortran. Try

```
...
INTEGER, parameter :: maxExampleTypes     =   5
TYPE ExampleInfo
    CHARACTER (len=50) :: ExDeckName
    INTEGER            :: A(maxExampleTypes)
    INTEGER            :: ExUnits
ENDTYPE ExampleInfo
TYPE(ExampleInfo) :: Example(10)

Example(1)%ExDeckName = 'test.dck'
Example(1)%A          = (/ 1,2,3,4,5 /)
...
```

If the values are supposed to be default values, put them into the type declaration:

```
...
INTEGER, parameter :: maxExampleTypes     =   5
TYPE ExampleInfo
    CHARACTER (len=50) :: ExDeckName = 'test.dck'
    INTEGER            :: A(maxExampleTypes) = (/ 1,2,3,4,5 /)
    INTEGER            :: ExUnits
ENDTYPE ExampleInfo
TYPE(ExampleInfo) :: Example(10)
...
```

Sample test program:

```
module testmod
  implicit none
  INTEGER, parameter :: maxExampleTypes     =   5
  ! Type with default values
  TYPE ExampleInfo
      CHARACTER (len=50) :: ExDeckName = 'test.dck'
      INTEGER            :: A(maxExampleTypes)= (/ 1,2,3,4,5 /)
      INTEGER            :: ExUnits
  ENDTYPE ExampleInfo

contains
  subroutine init_ExampleInfo(array)
    implicit none
    type(ExampleInfo), intent(out):: array(:)
    integer                       :: i

    do i=1,size(array)
      array(i)%ExDeckName = 'test.dck'
      array(i)%A          = (/ 1,2,3,4,5 /)
    enddo
  end subroutine
end module

program test
  use testmod
  implicit none
  TYPE(ExampleInfo) :: Example(10)

  ! Initialize manually
  ! call init_ExampleInfo(Example)
  write(*,*) Example(1)%ExDeckName, Example(1)%A

  ! Set new values
  Example(1)%ExDeckName = 'test2.dck'
  Example(1)%A          = (/ 5,4,3,2,1 /)

  write(*,*) Example(1)%ExDeckName, Example(1)%A
end program
```

Comment: The first option brings an error: "Executable statements are not allowed inside a MODULE" and I'd like to stick to this formulation

Comment: Can you compile the sample program I put into the answer? I guess there is a different issue in your code...

Comment: This one works fine but how to get the initialization out of the TYPE declaration ?

Comment: If you want to define a customized structure constructor you can do it as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262253/how-to-override-a-structure-constructor-in-fortran. This is Fortran 2003 and not implemented by every compiler, though.

Comment: @Amzocks Why would you *want* to remove the initialization of values from the `TYPE` declaration? The whole *point* of initializing in the `TYPE` declaration is to *avoid* declaring it elsewhere.

Comment: Right But I guess I was wrong telling you these are default values, it's more of an initialization for every index of Example

Comment: That is exactly what the initialization in the `type` declaration does! You could also use a loop in the main program to set all the values individually...

Comment: Sure, but is there any way to get the former writing ? Such that the array is initialized outside the TYPE declaration ?

Comment: Just remove the initialization in the `type` declaration and initialize the array in the main program (e.g. using a loop over all elements). The first write statement then should give some random output.

Comment: And is it possible within the module ?

Comment: You could write a subroutine in the module that does it for you ;-)

Comment: But it requires to be called by the main program, can't we get something intrinsic to the module that initialized the array as we use the module.

Comment: I have never heard of such an intrinsic - but what would be the use of that? You'll probably use the module more than once, and do you want to overload the array every time? What about arrays that are not defined inside the module (as is the case here)?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/b10932b4-0edd-4e61-89f2-6e478ccba9aa/entry/object_oriented_fortran_user_defined_constructors2?lang=en) for more about user defined constructors - this would also work for every array you declare (anywhere in your code).

Comment: Thanks again but it still puzzling why the statement DATA Example(1)%ExTypes/1,3,6,14,24,25,65,109,0,0,0,0/ works with one variable but not anymore if adding any other terms

Comment: *But it requires to be called by the main program, can't we get something intrinsic to the module that initialized the array as we use the module*....this makes no sense. You want the type to have an initial value but you don't want to call it and you don't want to define it in the `TYPE`. Are you even sure you know *what* it is that **you** want?