# Where is the class constructor?

Tags: class, oop, fortran

Consider [this code](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Object-oriented+programming) which is a tutorial for object oriented programming in Fortran:

```
module class_Circle
  implicit none
  private
  public :: Circle, circle_area, circle_print

  real :: pi = 3.1415926535897931d0 ! Class-wide private constant

  type Circle
     real :: radius
  end type Circle
contains
  function circle_area(this) result(area)
    type(Circle), intent(in) :: this
    real :: area
    area = pi * this%radius**2
  end function circle_area

  subroutine circle_print(this)
    type(Circle), intent(in) :: this
    real :: area
    area = circle_area(this)  ! Call the circle_area function
    print *, 'Circle: r = ', this%radius, ' area = ', area
  end subroutine circle_print
end module class_Circle

program circle_test
  use class_Circle
  implicit none

  type(Circle) :: c     ! Declare a variable of type Circle.
  c = Circle(1.5)       ! Use the implicit constructor, radius = 1.5.
  call circle_print(c)  ! Call a class subroutine
end program circle_test
```

I don't see any constructor for the class so how does `c = Circle(1.5)` actually work? What if there are more fields for the class how can I create a constructor which initialize them by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every user-defined derived type in Fortran has a default structure constructor. Its arguments are simply all components of the derived type in the order as they are declared.

Certain types of components may be optional in the default constructor such as the default-initialized components or allocatable components.

The structure constructor is a function which returns an object of the derived type and is named after the derived type. It [may be overloaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262253/how-to-override-a-structure-constructor-in-fortran) by a user-defined structure constructor.

---

*"What if there are more fields for the class how can I create a constructor which initialize them by default?"*

```
type obj
  real :: a
  integer :: n = 1
  real, pointer :: p => null()
  integer, allocatable :: ia
end type


type(obj) :: o
real, target :: pi = 3.14

o = obj(1.0)

o = obj(1.0, 2)

o = obj(1.0, p = pi)

o = obj(1.0, ia = 4)
```

are all legal. The components are argument of the default constructor in the order as they are declared, but some of them are optional. (Note, gfortran 4.8 does not compile the above code, but it is wrong)

Comment: Thanks, I want to create a timer object, is it possible to call system_clock and assign values to field that hold count max and count rate in a constructor that is executed automatically?

Comment: That sounds like a task for an user-defined constructor http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262253/how-to-override-a-structure-constructor-in-fortran or maybe not. I am not sure what you mean exactly.