# User defined constructor for Fortran derived type instance

Tags: constructor, fortran

This is my second question related to Fortran (I use C++, so forgive me my way of thinking).

I want to use OOP, to say, derived type in Fortran whenever appropriate.
In C++, you can use user defined constructor such as https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s16xw1a8.aspx

Here in Fortran, things are different.
The first thing I tried is from here:
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/b10932b4-0edd-4e61-89f2-6e478ccba9aa/entry/object_oriented_fortran_user_defined_constructors2?lang=en

Link is broken, so I pasted it here:

```
module m
  !...
  interface base
    module procedure new_base
  end interface

contains
  !...
  function new_base(I)
    integer, intent(in) :: I
    type(base) new_base

    allocate(new_base%data(I))
    new_base%data = I
  end function
  !...
end module
```

The interface above defines a user-defined constructor for type base. It is used in a similar way to a structure constructor. It can even take argument keywords.

Then I found some other ways to do it.
Here I listed a few approaches seemly to work but I only tested the first and second:

1. generic interface with the same name as the derived type they're supposed to construct, see link above;
2. use type-bound procedure (This is not even a "traditional" constructor)

   ```
   MODULE mymod
     TYPE mytype
       Private
       INTEGER :: x
       CONTAINS
       PROCEDURE, PASS :: init
     END TYPE
   CONTAINS
     SUBROUTINE init(this, i)
       CLASS(mytype), INTENT(OUT) :: this
       INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: i
       write(*,*) this%x
       IF(i > 0) THEN
         this%x = 1
       ELSE
         this%x = 2
       END IF
       write(*,*) this%x
     END SUBROUTINE init
   END
   PROGRAM test
     USE mymod
     TYPE(mytype) :: y
     CALL y%init(1)
   END PROGRAM
   ```
3. use Static Constructors or Structure Constructors (http://www.lahey.com/docs/lfenthelp/NLMOvUsInvConst.htm)
   But it appears that this is NOT for general Fortran http://www.lahey.com/docs/lfenthelp/NLMGSWhatIs.htm

So I haven't understood well enough what is most preferred and flexible approach to initialize/construct a derived type in practice, especially when I use nested derived type in development. I hope I can organize this topic with some help.

Comment: Did you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262253/how-to-override-a-structure-constructor-in-fortran and other related questions and answers? Wildcat's answer contains *a lot* of material and even comparisons with C++ and Java. I don't think repeating all that would be useful so it is better to narrow down your problems.

Comment: Both 1 and 2 can be and are used in practice. I like 1. more. 3. is not Fortran, but some Lahey specific language.  OOP in Fortran is used much less than in C++ (counting the number of OOP programmers in them) and you can't expect so much formalized rules. People are still finding their best approaches. Also don't forget that  *opinion-based questions are off-topic at Stack Overflow*.

Comment: @VladimirF ,Yes, indeed some of my ideas are actually from Wildcat 's answer.

Comment: So what do you have problems with? What do you miss there? Normally I would answer you in the spirit of the Wildcat's answer, so you better tell us what you are missing, otherwise you will just get what you already know.

Comment: Thanks, @VladimirF. When I firstly tested a first method, I got errors when I passed more arguments than the derived type member count (because I have nested derived type member). But I can pass the member derived type as an argument. Later on, I found that I can partially initialized the derived type without error. In C++, I can pass any number of argument in class constructor. So I am not sure what exactly the rule is in Fortran. I may do a few more tests.

Comment: You may be interested in "parameterized derived types".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, so I will assume you read well the answers at [How to override a structure constructor in fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262253/how-to-override-a-structure-constructor-in-fortran) and I will answer your problem raised in the comment. There is not enough place in the comment to answer that.

You can also make constructors in Fortran which accept variable number of arguments.

It is even possible with the default structure constructors which every derived type has by default. If you default-initialize a component, it is optional in the constructor. The same holds for allocatable and pointer components.

For type

```
type t1
  integer :: i = 1
  integer, pointer :: ip => null()
  integer, allocatable :: ap
end type
```

you can call the default constructor just as

```
instance = t1()
```

and it is perfectly legal, `i` will be 1, `ip` will point to `null` and `ap` will not be allocated.

Or you can call it as

```
 instance = t1(ap=5)
```

and the `ap` component will be allocated and set to 5 and the other components will be left default.

---

You can achieve similar stuff with user defined constructors just by making the arguments `optional`.

```
function t1_user(ap, i) result(res)
  type(t1) :: res
  integer, allocatable :: ap !this argument MUST be passed,
                             ! it does not have to be allocated
  integer, optional    :: i ! this argument is optional

  if (present(i)) then
    ...
  end if
end function
```

any type-bound procedure can of-course also have optional arguments.

---

As for the nested types, that is really best done with constructors as functions, no matter if they are default or user defined:

```
type inner
  real :: x, y
end type

type outer
  type(inner), allocatable :: in
  real :: z
end type

instance1 = outer(inner(1., 2.), 3.)

instance2 = outer(z=4.)
```