# Type-bound procedure that uses an external procedure with an explicit interface: Sometimes it compiles, sometimes not

Tags: interface, fortran, fortran90, derived-types

I screwed up on my previous question and had to delete it.  Here's a new one:

I got most of this code from [this quite helpful site](https://gist.github.com/n-s-k/522f2669979ed6d0582b8e80cf6c95fd):

```
module shape_mod

type shape
    integer :: color
    logical :: filled
    integer :: x
    integer :: y
contains
    procedure :: initialize
end type shape

type, extends(shape) :: rectangle
        integer :: length
        integer :: width
end type rectangle

type, extends(rectangle) :: square
end type square

interface
    subroutine initialize(sh, color, filled, x, y, length, width)
        import shape
        class(shape) :: sh
        integer :: color
        logical :: filled
        integer :: x
        integer :: y
        integer, optional :: length
        integer, optional :: width
  end subroutine
end interface

end module

subroutine initialize(sh, color, filled, x, y, length, width)

    ! initialize shape objects
    class(shape) :: sh
    integer :: color
    logical :: filled
    integer :: x
    integer :: y
    integer, optional :: length
    integer, optional :: width

    ! do stuff with shape

end subroutine initialize


program drv

use shape_mod

type(shape) :: sh

call sh%initialize(1, .true., 0, 0, 5, 10)

end program
```

This fails to compile (as it should, as pointed out by respondents to my previous question) with the error:

```
gfortran shape2.f90
shape2.f90:38:16:

     class(shape) :: sh
                1
Error: Derived type ‘shape’ at (1) is being used before it is defined
shape2.f90:46:7: Error: Symbol ‘sh’ at (1) has no IMPLICIT type
shape2.f90:47:7: Error: Symbol ‘sh’ at (1) has no IMPLICIT type
shape2.f90:48:7: Error: Symbol ‘sh’ at (1) has no IMPLICIT type
shape2.f90:49:7: Error: Symbol ‘sh’ at (1) has no IMPLICIT type
```

So, my question is, what can I do to get `subroutine initialize()` to know about `type shape`?  The only thing I can think of is to put a use statement in:

```
subroutine initialize(sh, color, filled, x, y, length, width)

    use shape_mod
    ! initialize shape objects
    class(shape) :: sh
    integer :: color
    logical :: filled
    ...
end subroutine initialize
```

But that gives me a new error:

```
gfortran shape2.f90
shape2.f90:37:8:

     use shape_mod
        1
Error: ‘initialize’ of module ‘shape_mod’, imported at (1), is also the name of the current program unit
```

How to write the subroutine is the one thing the link I referenced above does not tell.  Is there a way to do this?  Or does `initialiaze()` have to be part of shape_mod for this to work?

Comment: I don't understand why the subroutine shouldn't be in the module.  And I don't really understand why OP isn't programming something closer to a *derived type constructor*.  There are a few Qs and As hereabouts on the topic (eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46570745/user-defined-constructor-for-fortran-derived-type-instance) and plenty of references online.  Of course, my dimness is not much of a reason for OP to explain or to modify his code, it can safely be ignored.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark  You ask a good question.  The answer is that I don't know any better.  I was just following the link that I found.  There's still alot about OOP Fortran that I don't know.  Thanks for that link.  Very helpful.  Could you suggest a good book or two?

Comment: Well SO frowns on recommendations but if it didn't I'd suggest *Modern Fortran Explained* by Metcalf *et al*, *Scientific Software Design* by Rouson *et al*, and *Modern Fortran in Practice* by Markus.  But there's no single authoritative source of information that covers everything you might want to know about modern software design in Fortran, you'll have to get used to learning from SO Qs and As and snippets you find elsewhere on the 'net.  The PGI website has some good guides to this and that too.

Comment: Also, some list of refs... http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Object-oriented+programming [plus, *Fortran for Scientists and Engineers* (Chapman, 4th ed), Chap.16, and http://szaghi.github.io/zen-of-fortran-talk/index.html#/slide-0 http://szaghi.github.io/zen-of-fortran-talk/index.html#/slide-69 (use arrow to navigate)]

Comment: @francescalus  Thanks.  Will be very interested to read it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the module you have defined an interface for the external procedure `initialize`.  When you use this module in the subroutine definition you have access to the interface of the subroutine itself.

You cannot do this.

Fortunately, you can avoid having the interface accessible by

```
use shape_mod, only shape
```

---

Now, the above is necessary because of the design made to use an external procedure in the type binding.  In general, one would expect not to use an external procedure in this way.  As we've seen, there's the additional complexity in using an external procedure, both with having to use the module where the type is defined, but also in having to manually specify the procedure's interface.

There are times where an external interface would be useful, but here the purpose of the example leading to the question was perhaps pedagogical rather than simple.  There's no obvious reason here why `initialize` shouldn't be a module procedure.

Instead, consider the example

```
interface
  subroutine ext()
  end subroutine
end interface

type mytype
 contains
  procedure(iface), nopass :: ext
end type
```

The external subroutine `ext` doesn't have a passed-object dummy (the binding has `nopass`) so doesn't need the module in which `mytype` is defined.  This is a simplification.

Finally, as High Performance Mark comments, perhaps `initialize` needn't even be a binding name.  Instead a "constructor" could be used:

```
type mytype
end mytype

interface mytype
  procedure intialize_mytype
end interface
```

Details are left for the interested reader to find from other sources.