# "initial" statement / automatic constructor for a Fortran derived type

Tags: constructor, fortran

I am wondering if there is a constructor-like mechanism in Fortran for derived types, in such a way, that whenever an instance of a type is created, the constructor is called automatically. I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262253/how-to-override-a-structure-constructor-in-fortran) question, but it was unsatisfactory to me.

Schematic example for completeness:

```
module mod
integer :: n=5

type array
    real, dimension(:), allocatable :: val
  contains
    procedure :: array()
end type 

subroutine array(this)
  allocate(this%val(n))
end subroutine

end module
```

Now when I create an instance of `type(array) :: instance` I'd like the constructor `array(instance)` to be called automatically without any extra `call array(instance)` in the code added manually.

I found some promising information on [this](http://www.lahey.com/docs/lfenthelp/NLMOvElConstructors.htm) site, but nowhere else: It specifies a constructor-like mechanism with the type-bound procedure declared `initial,pass :: classname_ctor0`.  What standard is this? `ifort` in version 16 won't compile the example posted there and I have no standard available.

Comment: The Lahey site is not describing standard Fortran.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An 'initial' subroutine is not, unlike a final subroutine, part of a Fortran standard.

In a derived type certain components may have initial values, set by *default initialization*, such as

```
type t
  integer :: i=5
end type t
type(t) :: x  ! x%i has value 5 at this point
```

However, allocatable array components (along with some other things) may not have default initialization and always start life as unallocated. You will need to have a constructor or some other way of setting such an object up if you wish the component to become allocated.

In the case of the question, one thing to consider is the Fortran 2003+ parameterized type:

```
type t(n)
  integer, len :: n
  integer val(n)
end type
type(t(5)) :: x  ! x%val is an array of shape [5]
```

This naturally isn't the same this as an allocatable array component with an "initial" shape, but if you just want the component to be run-time initial customizable shape this could suffice.

Comment: The parameterized type looks promising and I think will be sufficient for my code. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is there any known performance penalties associated with the use of Parametrized Derived Types?

Comment: @King, for kind parameterized types one would be surprised by poorer performance, certainly.  For length parameterized types (or a mixture) there is of course an additional complexity for the compiler to handle, but I'd be disappointed if that had a significant impact.  I haven't measured any penalty but this level of abstraction could come with a cost