# Can I pass a variable to a derived type such that each instance of my derived type could have arrays of different lengths?

Tags: arrays, fortran, allocation, derived-types

What is the best way to organize 11 similar but varying size arrays in a program, without the allocatable property?

I'm imagining something like this:

```
TYPE MyType(i)
   integer, intent(in) :: i

   integer, dimension(i,i) :: A
   integer, dimension(2*i,i) :: B
   integer, dimension(i,2*i) :: C

end type MyType
```

Then in the main program I can declare something like this:

```
type(mytype), dimension(N) :: Array
```

Wherein the i'th element of 'Array' has access to three arrays A, B, and C and each of these three arrays have different sizes.

The problem I have currently is I am solving a QM problem and I have 11 different arrays that vary in size but all depend on the same parameter (as the size A, B and C all depend on i). The actually values of these arrays don't change either.

My program looks at different kinds of systems, each with their own A, B and C (just to keep the analogy going) and in each system A, B and C have a unique size.

If I knew I was looking at 6 different kinds of systems, I'd need 6 different copies of A, B and C.

Currently, A, B and C are not part of a derived type but instead are allocatable and recalculated at each iteration. This calculation takes upwards of a tenth of a second for the larger systems. But I average my results ~100,000 times which means this could offer some serious time savings. In addition, memory is not something I lack.

I tried calculating these arrays in another program and writing them to file and reading them when needed but unfortunately this was not faster than recalculating at the same time.

**Note:** Here is what my actual arrays look like:

```
  integer, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: fock_states      
  integer, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: PES_down, PES_up  
  integer, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: IPES_down, IPES_up 
  integer, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: phase_PES_down, phase_PES_up    
  integer, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: phase_IPES_down, phase_IPES_up 
  integer, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: msize       
  integer, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: mblock
```

Each array is a different size for each system.

**Edit:**

So what I really need is N copies of the arrays in the list just above this edit. The arrays belonging to the i'th copy have size that scales with i (e.g. PES_down has dimension (i,4**i)). As I understand it, this means that I need N different declarations of variables with type 'MyType'. This would normally be ok but the issue is that N is defined at compile time but can change between runs.

N does have a defined maximum but it seems like a lot of wasted memory when I know I won't be using the arrays.

Comment: So, you want your array variable, named Array, to have dimension N, where N comes from a user input? An also, each element of this array is of a derived type with array components, where the dimension of these arrays is proportional to the element position in Array?

Comment: Yes I do think that is accurate. I'm current doing it as you suggested in your comment. I haven't done much testing but my experience is has been that allocatable arrays are slower than those that are not. So my hope is that by defining it at compile time it will be much faster.

Answer (score 2):

(Relate to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52731185/2938526) for a more detailed explanation).

As @roygvib said in his comment, yes, using parameterized derived types in this case is not only possible, it is a perfect match. This is one of the main problem-cases PDT aims to solve.

```
type :: MyType(i)
  integer, len :: i
  integer, dimension(i,i) :: A
  integer, dimension(2*i,i) :: B
  integer, dimension(i,2*i) :: C
  ! (...)
end type
```

Then, in the main program, you would declare your object like this (where `i` is the known length parameter for the current kind of system):

```
type(mytype(i)), dimension(N) :: Array
```

But first, check the availability of this feature in your compiler.

Comment: Do you mean OP wants to store objects with different type-parameters in the same array? If yes, that's not possible, beacuse array elements must have the same storage size (formally, same type and kind).

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think pointer components are the only way to emulate jagged array

Comment: This does seem to match perfectly what I'm asking for. I realize now though that I need functionality in addition to what I described in my original post. I'll add an edit to clarify further.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it would be most straightforward to use a derived type containing `A`, `B`, and `C` with the size variable `i` and allocate them for each `i` using some initialization routine (here, `MyType_init()`).

```
module mytype_mod
    implicit none

    type MyType
        integer :: i
        integer, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: A, B, C
    end type
contains

    subroutine MyType_init( this, i )
        type(MyType), intent(inout) :: this
        integer, intent(in) :: i

        allocate( this % A( i,   i   ), &
                  this % B( 2*i, i   ), &
                  this % C( i,   2*i ) )

        this % A = 0  !! initial values
        this % B = 0
        this % C = 0
    end subroutine

end module

program main
    use mytype_mod
    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: N = 2
    type(MyType) :: array( N )
    integer i

    do i = 1, N
        call MyType_init( array( i ), i )

        array( i ) % A(:,:) = i * 10   !! dummy data for check
        array( i ) % B(:,:) = i * 20
        array( i ) % C(:,:) = i * 30
    enddo

    do i = 1, N
        print *
        print *, "i = ", i
        print *, "    A = ", array( i ) % A(:,:)
        print *, "    B = ", array( i ) % B(:,:)
        print *, "    C = ", array( i ) % C(:,:)
    enddo

end program
```

Result (with gfortran 8.1):

```
 i =            1
     A =           10
     B =           20          20
     C =           30          30

 i =            2
     A =           20          20          20          20
     B =           40          40          40          40          40          40          40          40
     C =           60          60          60          60          60          60          60          60
```

The `array(:)` in the main program can be allocatable, such that

```
type(MyType), allocatable :: array(:)

N = 6
allocate( array( N ) )
```

which may be useful when `N` is read in from an input file. Further, we can create a type-bound procedure from `MyType_init()` by changing the lines with `(*)` below (to use an OO style).

```
module mytype_m
    implicit none

    type MyType
        integer :: i
        integer, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: A, B, C
    contains
        procedure :: init => MyType_init   ! (*) a type-bound procedure
    end type

contains

    subroutine MyType_init( this, i )
        class(MyType), intent(inout) :: this   ! (*) use "class" instead of "type"
        ...
    end subroutine
end module

program main
    ...
    do i = 1, N
        call array( i ) % init( i )  ! (*) use a type-bound procedure
        ...
    enddo
    ...
end program
```

Comment: But I'm wondering if it is possible to use parametrized types for this purpose...?