# Constructors in fortran

Tags: fortran

I have 2 subclasses - ResultsPublisherInitial & ResultsPublisherFinal, both extending ResultsPublisher abstract class.

Abstract class is like:

```
type, public, abstract::   ResultsPublisher
   type(LAConstraintManagementResults), public, pointer::  lacmResults => null() 
   type(LACM_InputModel), public, pointer::                inputModel => null()
   type(LACM_ForecastResults), public, pointer::           forecast => null()
end type ResultsPublisher
```

Then i have 2 subclasses - ResultsPublisherInitial & ResultsPublisherFinal, each with constructor:

```
type, public, extends(ResultsPublisher)::  ResultsPublisherInitial  
   type(LACM_Model), public, pointer::      lacmModel => null()
end type ResultsPublisherInitial

interface ResultsPublisherInitial
   procedure:: ConstructorInitial
end interface

contains 

type(ResultsPublisherInitial) function ConstructorInitial(lacmResults, inputModel, forecast, lacmModel) 
   type(LAConstraintManagementResults), pointer::        lacmResults
   type(LACM_InputModel), pointer, intent(in)::          inputModel 
   type(LACM_ForecastResults), pointer, intent(in)::     forecast
   type(LACM_Model), pointer, intent(in)::               lacmModel

   ConstructorInitial%lacmResults => lacmResults
   ConstructorInitial%inputModel => inputModel
   ConstructorInitial%forecast => forecast
   ConstructorInitial%lacmModel => lacmModel
end function

-----------------
!
type, public, extends(ResultsPublisher)::  ResultsPublisherFinal  
   type(LR_Model), public, pointer::      lrModel => null()
end type ResultsPublisherFinal

interface ResultsPublisherFinal
   procedure:: ConstructorFinal
end interface

contains 

type(ResultsPublisherFinal) function ConstructorFinal(lacmResults, inputModel, forecast, lacmModel) 
   type(LAConstraintManagementResults), pointer::        lacmResults
   type(LACM_InputModel), pointer, intent(in)::          inputModel 
   type(LACM_ForecastResults), pointer, intent(in)::     forecast
   type(LACM_Model), pointer, intent(in)::               lacmModel

   ConstructorFinal%lacmResults => lacmResults
   ConstructorFinal%inputModel => inputModel
   ConstructorFinal%forecast => forecast
   ConstructorFinal%lacmModel => lacmModel
end function
```

As you can see, i have 2 constructors for each concrete type, introduced through interface procedure. Names of those procedures are **ConstructorInitial** and **ConstructorFinal**. 
Why i didnt name them only **Constructor**, as they are in different modules-scope, they should not overload each other? I tried to give them same name, but then i have been getting error when calling the constructor in client code. -> That means that for every class i had to add additional suffix after "Constructor".

I would like to have option to, in no mater how many different classes, use only **Constructor** word for object construction in every class. But in client-side code for object creation i will use exact name of that type.
Is this possible?

Comment: Welcome, use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions.

Comment: before anything, take a look to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4280567/2938526) to learn about the true nature of Fortran "custom constructors"

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues very interesting facts, thank you very much. But still, that does not answer my question.

Comment: Say i dont use procedure inside interface block. And I go only with "constructor structure" (as they call it in fortran book).In 4.4.15 Structure Constructor, and following rule described in Example 4. in Fortran 2003 HandBook, i would expect to successfully compile my code when invoking `TYPE(ResultsPublisherInitial):: initial` `initial = ResultsPublisherInitial(param1, param2, param3, param4)`. But i am getting error#6593: The number of expressions in a structure constructor differs from the number of components of the derived type.

Comment: i did short search, and i found this, but not sure about conclusion - how it is supposed to behave at the end. https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-visual-fortran-compiler-for-windows/topic/530458